# Google Mob Ad BannerAdWidgetState in Flutter Application returning errors

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies, google-mobile-ads

In my flutter application I am trying to implement google_mobile_ads in the pubspec.yaml I have added the following: `google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1`

I have created a banner_ad_widget.dart with the following:

```
class BannerAdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BannerAdWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BannerAdWidgetState createState() => _BannerAdWidgetState();
}

class _BannerAdWidgetState extends State<BannerAdWidget> with AdWithViewListener {
  late BannerAd _bannerAd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: MyAdListener(),
      request: const AdRequest(),
    )..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
      width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
      child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
    );
  }

  @override
  void onAdViewLoaded(Ad ad) {
    setState(() {});
  }
..................................
```

but I keep getting the following errors:

```
error: The class 'AdWithViewListener' can't be used as a mixin because it declares a constructor. (mixin_class_declares_constructor at [project] lib\utils\banner_ad_widget.dart:11)
error: The argument type 'MyAdListener' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BannerAdListener'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [project] lib\utils\banner_ad_widget.dart:20)
error: Classes can only extend other classes. (extends_non_class at [project] lib\utils\banner_ad_widget.dart:66)
```

**My question** how to fix this error so that it can work properly without these errors

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to add AdWithViewListener? You are not even using it anywhere.

You can remove `with AdWithViewListener` and your code will work fine.

What you are missing is dispose.

```dart
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bannerAd.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```